# using auxiliary verb to form question after question word: be vs do

Tags: questions, wh-questions

In the three example questions below, I couldn't determine which is the correct verb to use to form a question after question word. The answer to the question is *" the section falls under the HR Department".*

```
 What upper department is the section fell under?
 What upper department does the section fall under? 
 What is the name of the upper department that the section falls under?
```

Comment: A simple rule of thumb is that if you're asking about a verb in the simple present, the auxiliary is always *do*.  I smile : do I smile; She eats : does she eat; They run: do they run; etc.

Comment: @stangdon The rule for the present simple is that if there is no other auxiliary verb, use *do*. If there is an auxiliary, for example *be, can, may, might*, etc, then you cannot use and don’t need *do*.

Comment: It falls under x. Does it fall under x. It fell under x but we changed it. Fyi, we would probably say "come under" here and not fall under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is already an auxiliary (*BE*, *HAVE*, or a modal such as *can*, *will*, *may*)  then you put the auxiliary before the subject. Examples: *Is he going?* *Have you seen it?* *Should we wait?* *Will everybody come?*

If there is no auxiliary (only a main verb), you need to insert *DO* (do, did, does) before the subject. Examples: *Do they want to?* *Did you see it?*

Special case: in most varieties of English, *BE* never takes *DO*, even if it is the main verb. *Is that an elephant?*, not **Does that be an elephant?*.

For some speakers, mainly in Britain, *HAVE* is the same special case: *Have you any chocolate?*, where most people now would say *Do you have any chocolate?*

**Edit** I realised I haven't directly answered the question.
Your number 1 is not grammatical.
Your numbers 2 and 3 are both fine.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct.

> What upper department does the section fall under?

Is what I think most people would agree is correct, and what is grammatically correct.

The third one is also correct, but the extra text you add makes it sound slightly less natural, and it is not needed; unless, for example, each department has a name **and** something else, since then you would have to specify you wanted the name.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. I thought the same but I needed to check.

Comment: @MBR No problem! Also, if an answer does answer your question, remember to click the check mark under the votes button. It shows that the question’s answered for everyone.